# Multiple descriptors translate to for-each in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Assuming i have such simple xml file:

```
<store>
    <author name="Jack">
        <book>Book 1</book>
        <book>Book 2</book>
    </author>
    <author name="Mike">
        <book>Book 1</book>
    </author>
</store>
```

As you noticed Jack has 2 books. I need following output after XSLT translation:

```
    <list>
        <author>
            <name>Jack</name>
            <book>Book 1</book>
        </author>
        <author>
            <name>Jack</name>
            <book>Book 2</book>
        </author>
        <author>
            <name>Mike</name>
            <book>Book 1</book>
        </author>
    </list>
```

As you noticed in the output (after xslt translation) we have 2 authors Jack with each book it has. Can we do that in XSLT. Is there some analogue of for-each like in C/Java and etc?

What if for example Jack will have 7 books is it possible to automate this, so after translation it would be 7 Jack's  descriptors. Thank you.

Comment: Of course there is :) You should check the functions of xsl before asking that right here. Here the link for [xsl for-each](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_for_each.asp)

Comment: @user3433065 i was trying to do that with xsl-for each and i getting exceptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xsl:for-each` is a way of doing it.. More flexible way is using templates as in the following XSLT.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/store">
    <list>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="author/book"/>
    </list>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="book">
    <author>
        <name>
            <xsl:value-of select="../@name"/>
        </name>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </author>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And using `xsl:for-each` way would be just to put the second template's content within for-each as below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/store">
    <list>
        <xsl:for-each select="author/book">
            <author>
                <name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="../@name"/>
                </name>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </author>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </list>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Doesn't the `<xsl:copy-of select="."/>` picks all child-nodes? Ah OK, I got it now... you are in book and you pick the Value of it and write it down with his node?

Comment: `xsl:copy-of` does a deep copy of the node in the select attribute.. Here, `.` represents the current node which is book, hence does copies book..